# Javascript Opera + Safari issue

Tags: javascript

For some reason this page won't work in Opera + Safari http://dev.reggi.com/clients/mike2/

this is the main code I wrote that I believe is failing:

```
/*this script finds the multiples of the box_width and makes that the with of the container so the grid can be centred*/
/*sets variables*/
var box_width= 250 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5;
/*loads the width when page starts*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w= $(window).width();
    w-= (w-10) % box_width;
    if (w<box_width) w= box_width;
    $('.variable_window_width').width(w);

});
/*loads the new with onpage resize*/
$(window).bind('load resize', resizeFrame);
function resizeFrame() {
    var w= $(window).width();
    w-=((w-10) % box_width);
    if (w<box_width) w= box_width;
    $('.variable_window_width').width(w);

};

$(function(){
    $("#grid div").corner("4px");
});
```

Comment: You might want to move your `bind('load resize')` inside a `ready()` function. I've seen mysterious function bindings fail in a number of browsers because they're not done in the `ready()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Won't work" - Is not an accurate description.

First you should fix your CSS and HTML, Opera 11 doesn't render the site ***at all***, Dragonfly complains:

```
dispaly is an unknown property

Line 10:
  #inner_site_header_right{float:right;dispaly:inline;text-align:right;padding-rig
  ---------------------------------------------^
```

and:

```
Syntax error before comment end ("-->")

Line 15:
  //-->
  -----^
```

Next time do at least some basic debugging before coming here.

Safari I cannot test, but Chrome 8 seems to work, but then again, we don't even know what's not working.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: To explain the second one, don't comment out your CSS, especially not that way. JavaScript single-line comments are not valid in CSS (which only supports `/* comment text */`).